# resize column width in bar chart and line chart after brush using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
[here after filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY3fF.png)
[and the default when reload chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGR1O.png)
[the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFBP2.png)
[function brush values of columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EViyp.png)
```

> xScaleBand = d3
> .scaleBand()
> .domain(defaultBarChart.map((d) => d.D01_BSEG_HKONT))
> .range([0, width])
> .padding(0.2);
> yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-maxValue, maxValue]).range([height, 0]);
> const bar = d3.select("#barChart").select("svg").datum(stackedData);
>
> bar
> .select("#x-axis")
> .transition()
> .duration(1000)
> .call(d3.axisBottom(xScaleBand))
> .selectAll("text")
> .attr("font-weight", "normal")
> .style("text-anchor", "start")
> .attr("dx", ".6em")
> .attr("dy", ".15em")
> .attr("transform", "rotate(30)")
> .style("font-size", "15px")
> .style("font-weight", "bold");
>
> d3.select("#yaxis-2")
> .transition()
> .duration(1000)
> .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(null, "s"))
> .selectAll("text")
> .style("font-size", "13px")
> .attr("fill", "#000")
> .style("font-weight", "bold");
>
> const colorScale = d3
> .scaleOrdinal()
> .domain(["D01_ZF_MONTH_TB_MOINS_GL_USD", "D01_ZF_MONTH_ABS_TB_GL_USD"])
> .range(["steelblue", "brown"]);
>
> var D01_ZF_MONTH_TB_MOINS_GL_USD = [];
> var D01_ZF_MONTH_ABS_TB_GL_USD = [];
>
> for (a in stackedData[0]) {
> if (!isNaN(parseInt(a))) {
> D01_ZF_MONTH_TB_MOINS_GL_USD.push(stackedData[0][a]);
> }
> }
>
> for (a in stackedData[1]) {
> if (!isNaN(parseInt(a))) {
> D01_ZF_MONTH_ABS_TB_GL_USD.push(stackedData[1][a]);
> }
> }
>
> var g1 = d3
> .select("#D01_ZF_MONTH_TB_MOINS_GL_USD")
> .selectAll("rect")
> .data(D01_ZF_MONTH_TB_MOINS_GL_USD);
>
> g1.enter().append("svg:rect");
> g1.exit().remove();
>
> var g2 = d3
> .select("#D01_ZF_MONTH_ABS_TB_GL_USD")
> .selectAll("rect")
> .data(D01_ZF_MONTH_ABS_TB_GL_USD);
>
> g2.enter().append("svg:rect");
> g2.exit().remove();
>
> d3.select("#bar")
> .transition()
> .duration(1000)
> .selectAll("g")
> .selectAll("rect")
> .attr("x", function (d) {
> if (d.data.D01_BSEG_HKONT !== undefined) {
> return xScaleBand(d.data.D01_BSEG_HKONT);
> }
> })
> .attr("width", xScaleBand.bandwidth())
> .attr("y", function (d) {
> return yScale(Math.max(d[1], d[0]));
> })
> .attr("height", function (d) {
> if (d.data.D01_BSEG_HKONT !== undefined) {
> return Math.abs(yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]));
> }
> });`
> console.log(xScaleBand.bandwidth());
> I don't know how to shrink the bar chart column after data brush, can someone give me the solution?
> have tried solution calculate width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33zZv.png)](https://stackoverflow.com)
> but when i get the error, if i brush the line chart first, then hit the bar chart again,
> the returned data does not match the previous access interval, such as when I surf on the previous line
> and then continue brush in the bar with 4 columns, on the screen only 1 column] or yes another way to
> recalculate the size of the columns in the chart?
> Could you please let me know why this error occurs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.